# How to locate Button followed by card_header-title containing specific text in sample html

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

How to select Actions Button followed by the Div class containing known Text ( for example, `card_header-title"Addresses"` in this case) in Robot Test Framework?

The page contains several span table sections and each of them has its own actions and show-history buttons. To select the specific Actions button, I could use its xpath, but I am trying to access all sections in a `for` loop and the xpath of actions button in one section changes from the other, so hard coding is not an option for me. Would someone please help.

```html
<div class="attribute-group-header card__header">
  <h3 class="attribute-group-title card__header-title">Addresses</h3>
  <div class="floatright">
    <input type="button" class="action small btn" value="Actions">
    <input type="button" class="showHistory action small btn" value="ShowHistory">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you say you don't want to use Xpaths but maybe one of these examples could help. I don't see any other way of achieving what you're asking for other than having id's supplied on the buttons.

You could use an xpath locator that first finds the text of the "attribute-group-title card__header-title" element and then selects the following sibling div, followed by the input:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Addresses')]/following-sibling::div[1]//input[@value='Actions']
```